# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in 3D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, neural-network

I'm trying to make a jagged array for a neural network and this is giving me an out of bounds error...

```
int[] sizes = {
    layer1, layer2, layer3
};
int k = sizes.length - 1;
double[][][] net = new double[k][][];
int i;
for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
   net[i] = new double[sizes[i]][];
for (int j = 0; j < sizes[i]; j++)
   net[i][j] = new double[sizes[i + 1]];
```

The size of y in `net[x][ ][y]` should be equal to the size of `net[x+1][y][ ]`.

I did it on paper and I thought that this would work.

Comment: Did you try debugging your program?

Comment: Which line is failing, and what exactly is the error? (And please format your code to make it more readable...) Do you really not have braces, by the way? If so, that's the issue...

Comment: @NateCook3 Not sure what you are trying to achieve because I don't know what `layer1`, `layer2` and `layer3` hold. See my answer for the reason why you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Not really sure how this is a duplicate of the one you marked.

Comment: If you already have an answer, then please resist from making drastic changes to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int[] sizes = {
    layer1, layer2, layer3
};
int k = sizes.length - 1;
```

So, `k` is equal to 2.

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
   net[i] = new double[sizes[i]][];
```

After that loop `i` is equal to 2.

```
for (int j = 0; j < sizes[i]; j++)
   net[i][j] = new double[sizes[i + 1]];
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
                          ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Boom, `sizes[i + 1]` throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, since `sizes` has only indices 0, 1 and 2 and you are referring to `sizes[3]`.